# Have RecyclerView load page 1 automatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a `RecyclerView` in my Android project. I have a function, `getPosts(int page)` that adds new items to the relevant `ArrayList`. This is called in `onLoadMore()`.

Now, when the activity starts, nothing happens. So I decided to call `getPosts(1)` manually from `onCreate()`. The problem with this is now page 1 is being loaded twice. Once by me in `onCreate()`, and for some reason again in `onLoadMore()`. Subsequent pages load perfectly.

So is there some way to tell the `RecyclerView` to start loading? If not, what should I do here?

Edit: As requested, here is a summary of my code:

```
private ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;
private RecyclerView recycler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_diary);

    //...

    postArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    recycler = ((RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerDiary));
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(((LinearLayoutManager) recycler.getLayoutManager())){
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            Log.d("devlog", "Requesting page "+page+" from onLoadMore()");
            getPosts(page);
        }
    };

    recycler.setAdapter(new PostAdapter(postArrayList, new RecyclerViewClickHandler()));
    recycler.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

    Log.d("devlog", "Requesting page 1 from onCreate()");
    getPosts(1);

}

//...

private void getPosts(int page){

    int insertStartPos = postArrayList.size();
    Post[] posts;
    //get posts from the backend

    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
        postArrayList.add(posts[i]);
    }

    DiaryAdapter adap = ((DiaryAdapter) recycler.getAdapter());
    if (insertStartPos == 0){
        adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        adap.notifyItemRangeInserted(insertStartPos, bundleSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your method `onLoadMore()` and `getNewItems()`

Comment: add your `activity` code

Comment: populate the `RecyclerView.Adapter` and not the `RecyclerView` ....something alike `new DiaryAdapter(context, pageSize, pageNum);`

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid calling getNewItems(1) twice that means that you should have a global variable on your class, for example, named currentPage that is initialised with value 1 and is incremented every time you call getNewItems().

From now on call

```
getNewItems(currentPage);
currentPage++;
```

Comment: This works, but there has to be a better solution. I feel like the `page` parameter is there for a reason.